# Pandas - Group by Period of Time / deleting consecutive rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

What's the best way to solve following problem:

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
Index  Date                  Name       Product
01     2017-09-6 18:01:15    Mike       xxx
02     2017-09-6 18:02:35    Mike       yyy
03     2017-09-6 18:07:25    Mike       xxx
04     2017-09-6 18:09:35    Mike       yyy
05     2017-09-6 18:09:39    John       yyy
06     2017-09-6 18:23:15    Mike       xxx
07     2017-09-6 18:25:35    Mike       xxx
08     2017-09-6 18:50:39    John       yyy
09     2017-09-6 18:58:15    Mary       xxx
10     2017-09-6 19:07:20    Mary       xxx
11     2017-09-6 19:07:25    Mike       zzz
12     2017-09-6 19:09:09    Mary       xxx
13     2017-09-6 21:03:45    Mary       zzz
14     2017-09-6 21:12:15    Mike       yyy
15     2017-09-6 21:20:15    Mike       yyy
```

This dataframe represents product searches of multiple users in a database.
What I want to do now is creating a dataframe, which filters out multiple searches of the same user on the same product within a certain period of time (let's say 15 minutes) - in other words: every additional search within 15 minutes after the first search meeting the name and product criterias should be deleted.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
Index  Date                  Name       Product
01     2017-09-6 18:01:15    Mike       xxx
02     2017-09-6 18:02:35    Mike       yyy
05     2017-09-6 18:09:39    John       yyy
06     2017-09-6 18:23:15    Mike       xxx
08     2017-09-6 18:50:39    John       yyy
09     2017-09-6 18:58:15    Mary       xxx
11     2017-09-6 19:07:25    Mike       zzz
13     2017-09-6 21:03:45    Mary       zzz
14     2017-09-6 21:12:15    Mike       yyy
```

What's the best way to solve this in Python?

THX & BR
bdriven

Comment: In your result, Index 14 and 15 are within 15min of each other. Do you mean anchoring only on the very first search?

Comment: sry, that was a mistake, I've corrected it and deleted index 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to loop over the Date series to create a filter.

(Let's assume your Date column for each [Name, Product] group is sorted ascending already.)

```
def date_filter(s):
    s = s.values
    anchor = s[0]
    res = [False] * len(s)
    res[0] = True

    for idx, x in enumerate(s):
        if (x - anchor) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm') > 15:
            res[idx] = True
            anchor = x

    return res

df[ df.groupby(['Name','Product'])['Date'].transform(date_filter) ]
```

Comment: Hi jf328, thx for your answer. I also thought about this solution, but I've wanted to avoid any loops or iterations. Maybe there will be an additional answer how to solve it with onboard pandas methods, otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @bdriven, pandas can bin the data into 15min intervals easily, then you can take the first one in each bin. But that's not exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @ jf328: sry, for the delay, but the corresponding project was on hold for a few weeks. But your solution worked perfectly fine and therefore it got the checkmark. Many THX from Vienna - bdriven